# Programmatically add featured image with ALT text in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, image, text, alt, wordpress-featured-image

There are examples of how to add post with featured image programmatically in wordpress, but I need to add post with featured image and ALT text too. How can I do something like that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at the source for the `wp_get_attachment_image` function, you can see how the alt text is being fetched:

```
'alt'   => trim(strip_tags( get_post_meta($attachment_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true) ))
```

From there it is easy enough to figure out how to update the alt text.

```
update_post_meta($attachment_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', 'My Alt Text');
```